# Can I use a dynamic method name in a trait?

Tags: php, traits

I have a bundle of classes, which do similar tasks and there for have a lot of duplicated code. I extracted the duplicate code into a trait.
The method in the trait calls upon a method in the class which uses it.

What the trait does is checking if content was found under a cache key and call upon a method to get fresh content, if nothing is found. With most classes it is straight forward, but a few classes have two methods for fetching fresh content, which are named differently.

How can I get those different functions / function names in my trait method?

I tried using a dynamic name for the method, but this results in an exception on the first line of the else branch where the method is called:

```php
    private function useKeyedCache(
        string $key,
        ?string $language = PucSapLanguage::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
        string $fetchFunctionName = 'fetchFreshContent'
    ): array {
        /** @var CacheItemInterface $cacheItem */
        $cacheItem = $this->cache->getItem($key);
        if ($cacheItem->isHit()) {
            $content = $cacheItem->get();
        } else {
            $content = $this->$fetchFunctionName($language);
            $cacheItem->set($content);
            $cacheItem->expiresAfter($this->expiration);
            if (null !== $this->cache) {
                $this->cache->save($cacheItem);
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

What is the proper way to solve this? Would using a closure instead of a dynamic method name do the trick? I tried call_user_func, but it also throws an exception.

With a fixed method name the trait works like a charm.

Comment: What is the thrown exception? and why don't you just check if a method exists and if not then handle it accordingly. Something like https://3v4l.org/jlV9O

Comment: If the default method doesn't exist I still don't know which one I should use instead. So I need the information which method should be used.

Comment: @Rain so "handle accordingly" is the challenge here.